# Put a Limit to Appended Data (Like Pagination) - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

How can i put a limit on appended Data? Something Like Pagination.

E.g If I have **appended 5 comments**, Its should show me **3 latest comments**, other 2 comments should be **hidden** and should appear when click on **Show More Comments**. All i want to do with Jquery.

**Check Out Js Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/1/

Please take a look at this Image. Just to Clarify my Point:

[image]

**I am Providing my Code here too:**

**HTML:**

```
      <p>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_more">Add More</a>
      </p>

<table border="0" width="500" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody class="append_data"></tbody>

<tr>
  <td> 
      <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
  </td> 
</tr> 

</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#description{
    width:400px;    
}

.description_text{
    border:#333333 solid 1px;
    width:400px !important;
}

.append_data{
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.add_more').click(function()
                     {
                        var description = $('#description').val();
                        $(".append_data").append('<div class="description_text">'+description+'</div><br><br>');
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Append div element for each comment and use ".slice" to show the last 3 and hide the rest. [api.jquery.com/slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice) is the thing you should be looking for.

```
$(".comment_container").slice(0, -3).hide(); //will hide divs except the last 3.
```

Comment: Can you Update My Fiddle ?